# Find all child and grandchild nodes from given parent id PHP

Tags: php

I am working in referral system. 
let's say user A invites user B and user C. And then User B invites user D and user C invites user E and so on. How can i iterate through all the child and grandchild node?

Here is the example data in my db

```
ID       name       referral_id
1        user A     null//assume the tree starts from here
2        user B     1
3        user C     1
4        user D     2
5        user E     3
```

How can I create a function that will retrieve user A as a parent and then list down user B(with sub-node D) and user C(with sub-node E)??

I am using CI and this is my query to retrieve the 2 sub-nodes from the parent id

```
$downline_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE referral_id = '1'")
//above query will return user B and C as result.. hardcoded for example

$downline = array();
foreach($downline_query as $result){
   $downline[] = array( 
       "name" => $result['name'],
       "id"   => $result['id']
   );
}
//above $downline array will only contain user B and C. I don't know where to go again after this step.. 

$records = array("data"=>$downline);
echo json_encode($records);
```

I don't know where to go after this step.. Have done several type of algorithm including while loop and foreach loop. but it is still not that "dynamic".

Please be informed that I just need the names and id of all the children and grandchildren.. It doesn't have to be multidimensional array. as long as i can get all the children and granchildren and great-grand-children is already okay..

I am planning to save all the children and grandchildren and so on into the $downline array. So all will be in 1 array without a multidimensional array

really need guidance on how to do this.. never done this hierarchy thingy before.. thank you :)

Comment: For this kind structure query.. Just take a look at http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ .. This link very usefull.

Comment: Please review this link question my help you. [For Create Tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433056/unable-to-retrieve-the-sub-categories/34433727#34433727)

Comment: a single loop wont work for this, you have to have access to all data before trying to organize them, otherwise you will miss some if they are out of order.  IN the first loop you have to order them by ID, preferably with that as the key, then in the second loop, you build a second array by pulling the associated data out of the first array by ID/KEY,

Answer (score 0):

This should do, assuming `$downline_query` contains all the rows you need. IE 1 DB query.

```
$affilites = [];
$parents = []
foreach($downline_query as $row){
   if( $row['referral_id'] ){
       if( !isset(  $affilites[$row['referral_id']] ) ){
             $affilites[$row['referral_id']] = [];
       }
       $affilites[$row['referral_id']][] = $row;
   }else{
       $parents[$row['id']] = $row;
   }
}
// you now have 2 arrays 1 of parents, one of children. now just combine ( shown below )
$parent = [
    1 => ['ID'=>1,'name'=>'user A', 'referral_id' =>null],  
];

$affiliate = [
    1 => [
            ['ID'=>2,'name'=>'user B', 'referral_id' =>1],
            ['ID'=>3,'name'=>'user C', 'referral_id' =>1],
        ],
    2 => [['ID'=>4,'name'=>'user D', 'referral_id' =>2]],
    3 => [['ID'=>5,'name'=>'user E', 'referral_id' =>3]],
    5 => [['ID'=>16,'name'=>'user F', 'referral_id' =>5]],
];


print_r(getparents( $parent, $affiliate));

function getparents( $parent, $affiliate ){
    $result = [];
    foreach ($parent as $row ){
        $id = $row['ID'];

        $result[] = $row;

        if( isset($affiliate[$id]) ){
         //no children
            $result[$id]['children'] = getparents( $affiliate[$id], $affiliate ); //recurse
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

And the final output

```
 Array(
        [0] => Array(
                [ID] => 1
                [name] => user A
                [referral_id] =>
                [children] => Array(
                        [0] => Array(
                                [ID] => 2
                                [name] => user B
                                [referral_id] => 1
                                [children] => Array(
                                        [0] => Array(
                                                [ID] => 4
                                                [name] => user D
                                                [referral_id] => 2
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        [1] => Array(
                                [ID] => 3
                                [name] => user C
                                [referral_id] => 1
                                [children] => Array(
                                        [0] => Array(
                                                [ID] => 5
                                                [name] => user E
                                                [referral_id] => 3
                                                [children] => Array(
                                                        [0] => Array(
                                                                [ID] => 16
                                                                [name] => user F
                                                                [referral_id] => 5
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

Comment: sir will it keep iterating from the child nodes to all the grandchild nodes ?

Comment: No it will only work one deep, you would have to make it recursive to do that.  But you would be better off using a nested set in that case, or materialized path.  Because then you have a hierarchy instead of a parent child relationship.

Comment: @Vinfoster0701 - please see my updated answer which is now recursive,

Answer (score -1):

You can try a recursive function :

```
function get_referrals ($referral_id){
    $downline = array();
    $downline_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE referral_id = '$referral_id'");
    foreach($downline_query as $result){
       $downline[] = array(
           "name" => $result['name'],
           "id"   => $result['id']
       );
       $downline['invited'] = get_referrals($result['id']);  # <--- recursive !!!
    }
    return $downline;
}
```

and get your $downline

```
$downline = get_referrals(1);


print_r($downline);
```

Comment: I would recommend using prepared statements, as your answer is susceptible to sql injection, ie `get_referrals("'; DROP TABLE users; --");`

Comment: It only a solution... not the final code. the implementation should be done by the developer Vinfoster0701. It will produce the desired result.